# Good way to view/print descriptive statisctics of a large data set in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics, export

I have rather large data set (67 columns, 9800 rows). I want to check the descriptive statistics. Here is what I do so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h'], columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
print(df.describe())
print(df.isnull().sum())
```

I am trying to get the basic descriptive statistics and the NaN-count. However, all prints are abridged given the large dataset.

What is a smart way to show without getting an abridged report? 
How can I export the produced tables to Excel? 
Is pandas the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.describe().append(df.isnull().sum().rename('isnull'))

             one       two     three
count   5.000000  5.000000  5.000000
mean    0.003423 -0.121164  0.386899
std     0.532280  0.749847  0.614877
min    -0.596886 -0.767480 -0.621084
25%    -0.254336 -0.641685  0.258331
50%    -0.022049 -0.587911  0.657703
75%     0.048015  0.631354  0.693988
max     0.842374  0.759903  0.945556
isnull  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

***export with `to_excel`***

```
df.describe().append(df.isnull().sum().rename('isnull')).to_excel(filename)
```

Comment: Cool! That is a elegant way! Can I export the table, too?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for add new row with `NaN` statistics:

```
df1 = df.describe()
df1.loc['isnull'] = df.isnull().sum()
print (df1)
             one       two     three
count   5.000000  5.000000  5.000000
mean    0.237377 -0.346928 -0.322925
std     0.890415  0.883372  0.603782
min    -1.293332 -1.317518 -0.936159
25%     0.415596 -1.043694 -0.730677
50%     0.503251 -0.318196 -0.348271
75%     0.520425  0.053760 -0.228624
max     1.040943  0.891006  0.629104
isnull  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

And then use [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df1.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks! But the print is still abridged. More, `print(df.count())` merely shows the non-NaN but not the other statistics (mean, count, q1, etc.).